# Jquery RockPaperScissors game won't work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

on my `compare function` I'd like to add class to the `label' in order to show the result.

What I want to achieve is

- By click the .button addClass `<label class="win">`to the winner
- and addClass `<label class="lose">` to the loser.

its nearly there but doesn't seems to be consistent.

Also the simulation by clicking `computervcomputer` buttons show do the same.

Sorry for the fiddle but the Snippet here wasn't working.
https://jsfiddle.net/e9ew0cne/1/

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem. I've tried your code and had a look with the JS console and it seems that the `<span class="result">` gets the correct class (`win` or `lose` or tie depending on the `case`).
Maybe you should rephrase your question for clarity.

Comment: Did about 50 runs, everything seems to be working fine :P

Comment: By click the .button addClass <label class="win"> to the winner and add class to the loser. 
and addClass <label class="lose"> to the loser.

Comment: @LaurensSwart i know is tricky to understand but I need to make it for user friendly  by adding the classes correctly

Comment: Code goes in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**
Answer completely revised upon further understanding the question.

```
        function compare(choice1, choice2) {
            if (choice1 == choice2) {

                $(".result").text("Tie!").addClass('tie');
                $(".reset").addClass('xs-block');
            } else if (
            (choice1 == "rock" && choice2 == "scissors") || (choice1 == "scissors" && choice2 == "paper") || (choice1 == "paper" && choice2 == "rock")) {
                $(".result").text("You win!").addClass('win');

                $('#'+choice1).next('label').addClass('win');
                $('#'+choice2).next('label').addClass('lose');

                $(".reset").addClass('xs-block');
            } else {
                $(".result").text("You lose!").addClass('lose');

                $('#'+choice2).next('label').addClass('win');
                $('#'+choice1).next('label').addClass('lose');

                $(".reset").addClass('xs-block');
            }

        };
```

I have [a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a2ny1zzd/2/), but the main change I made was the function above. Instead of trying to find the labels via a collection of classes in the `<i>` tags, I switched it to using the unique `id` of the `button` tags. This meant changing the *jquery* from using `prev` to `next`. Plus there was a bug in the original that meant the computer choice was always marked as losing...

Comment: thanks, please have a look at this fiddle, it shows the class in action but doesn't work properly.  https://jsfiddle.net/e9ew0cne/1/

Comment: Okay, that helped me completely revise my answer. I didn't notice originally that you were trying to hook on the class of the `i` tags. New answer takes this and a bunch of other bugs into account...